# Mostrar 2 decimales de un double

Tags: java

Tengo un int de tamaño del 1 al 3, y quiero dividirlo en 100 y guardarlo en un double, el problema es que al resultar un 0.01, 0.02 o 0.03 solo me toma 0.0

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int porcentajeEntero = sc.nextInt();



double porcentaje = porcentajeEntero / 100;
System.out.println(porcentaje);
```

Comment: Agregá el código a la pregunta para ver que es lo que te está pasando. Y tené en cuenta que el tipo double puede no reflejar bien valores decimales, si necesitás exactitud por ejemplo para importes monetarios mejor usa BigDecimal.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu código? Si estas utilizando el operador / con enteros, el resultado es correcto, pues 1/100 = 0, 2/100 = 0, etc. Aparte es el residuo, que en el primer caso sería 1. Si lo necesitas como double, deberías convertirlos a double antes.

Comment: Ya mostre mi codigo, sucede que solo es un pequeño proyecto para la universidad y no lo consideraba util para mi explicacion

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que el operador `/` entre enteros te da un cociente y un residuo de tipo entero. 1/100 tiene 0 como cociente y 1 como residuo.

Debes hacer el cambio en tu instrucción:

```
double porcentaje = porcentajeEntero / 100;
```

Por

```
double porcentaje = porcentajeEntero / 100.0;
```

Para que efectivamente, obtengas el cociente como double

Answer (score 2):

El problema que tienes no es que el `double` te *tome* menos decimales de los que arroja como resultado la división, sino que es que estás haciendo una división entre enteros, y entre enteros el resultado del operador `/` es también entero.

Es decir, `450 / 100`, da como resultado `4`, no `4.5`, como aparentemente esperas.

La solución es sencilla, puedes forzar a que se realice una división entre números de coma flotante, lo cual te va a dar aproximadamente el resultado que esperas, por ejemplo:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int porcentajeEntero = sc.nextInt();
double porcentaje = (porcentajeEntero * 1.0) / 100;
System.out.println(porcentaje);
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma que logra el mismo efecto que @jachguate y @JYass:

```
double porcentaje = (double) porcentajeEntero / 100;
```